# Implementing annotations based form delivery system which allows to send the required fields in form as annotations in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mailgun, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

Is there any way to implement the following requirement:

- An ASP.NET MVC application to cater the email delivery of PDF forms to the authorized individual, which should only allow those specific fields in the form which he/she is supposed to fill.
- I'm using Syncfusion's PDF viewer to implement one half of this requirement, so the entire implementation needs to be in Syncfusion for ASP.NET MVC
- It should not allow the user to submit the form without completing required fields.
- The form when required to be sent to multiple users, each user should be prompted to fill only those form fields which are tagged against him/her.
- At last, the status tracker in the main application, which tracks which stage is complete and which is not. Eg: Out of 2 users, one user has finished his task, so the status would be like Stage 1/2 completed.

I haven't been able to find any leads to implement in .NET stack. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to generate HTML forms based on PDF files with input fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the form fields on submitting the form field values. We have provided the code snippet and the documentation for the same. Kindly refer to it and let us know if this helps.

Sample: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/PdfViewer/FormDesigner#/fluent

[Validation code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcK6T.png)

Validation documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/documentation/pdfviewer/how-to/redirect-to-home-page

The other requirements can be achieved at your application level.